# chef include recipes override attributes

Tags: attributes, include, overriding, chef-infra

When you include a recipe in another recipe how to do you override the attributes.

It looks the include recipe used the default attributes not the attributes of the recipe when it was run previously in the run_list.

Answer (score 20):

When you are creating a wrapper cookbook, it is common to override attributes.

Suppose, you have my_web_server cookbook with `my_web_server/recipes/default.rb` like this:

```
include_recipe "apache2"
```

And you would like to override attribute default_site_enabled from apache2 cookbook.
Then your file `my_web_server/attributes/default.rb` should look like:

```
override['apache']['default_site_enabled'] = true
```

And don't forget to specify dependencies in `my_web_server/metadata.rb` like:

```
depends "apache2"
```

Comment: Does this only work for Chef server? Doesn't seem to work for me on Chef solo, using Chef 12.0.3.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, was needing some similar info to override attributes on the chef_nginx cookbook.

Answer (score 5):

I often use roles for override attributes.

Say I have two cookbooks, one for my sweet_rails_app, one to install/configure apache and passenger to install my app on top of.

In my sweet_rails_app_cookbook I may have:

```
# coding: UTF-8
# Cookbook Name:: sweet_rails_app
# Recipe:: default
include_recipe 'apache_passenger_cookbook::default'
... # recipe code
```

All attributes in both cookbooks set at the default level in either cookbook.

```
# coding: UTF-8
name 'sweet_rails_app'
description 'Deploys Sweet Rails App'

run_list "recipe[sweet_rails_app_cookbook]"

base_dir = '/opt/sweet_rails_app'

override_attributes(
  sweet_rails_app: {
    base_dir: base_dir,
    ... # more override attributes
  },
  apache_passenger: {
    document_root: base_dir
  }
)
```

Then the role is all that I need to add to the run_list for the node.  This also has the added bonus of controlling the order of execution of the two cookbooks.